# use gridview row control in sqldatasource insert command

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use a label from another row in the gridview and insert it in a table when the user clicks the button which is in its own column.

my problem is that i cant get bookno which finds the label set to the @bookno in my sqldatasource

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim selectedRow As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)



        Dim bookno As Label = CType(selectedRow.FindControl("label1"), Label)
        Dim why As TextBox = CType(selectedRow.FindControl("textbox2"), TextBox)
        Dim yesint As Integer = 1
        Dim sql As SqlDataSource = CType(selectedRow.FindControl("sqldatasource4"), SqlDataSource)
        sql.InsertParameters.Add(bookno.Text, 0)


        sql.Insert()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? And what does bookno.Text contains? Is it the parametername or the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Dim bookno As Label = CType(selectedRow.Parent.FindControl("label1"), Label)
```

and see if you get a valid control for `bookno`. If it works, do the same for other `FindControl()` calls.

Comment: what i did was just copied the sqldatasource into the booking template field set the label1 as the parameter control and just copied back the datasource to my outher templatefield and it worked great